# creating an object from templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates, object, initialization, instantiation

I have these structs.

```
struct V
{
    int data[2];
    V(int a,int b)
    {
        data[0] = a;
        data[1] = b;
    } 
}

typedef std::vector<int> X;

struct A
{
    B<V> member1;
    B<X> member2;

    A(V member1_, X member2_) : member1(member1_),member2(member2_){}
}

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    T data;
    B(T data_){data = data_;}
}
```

How do I create an object of struct A? I wish to declare an object A like so

```
A a;
```

and then use it later to assign member1 to it. This is because I would not know B's data until later in the program run. But the compiler would not let me and complains about default constructor in B, saying I don't have one. How do I write default constructors for B and A then while B is a template? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use a `boost::optional<B<V>>` and assign a value later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give struct B an empty default constructor. It will run the default constructor of data, too. You just need to make sure that T has a default constructor, too (actually, the current code of yours requires that, too - members are constructed before opening brace of constructor).

Comment: Ok, I've given B empty default constructor. When I tried to declare a variable of A like so 

    A a;

the compiler gives 'undefined symbols for architecture...' error message. Maybe the compiler does not know the type of B's member 'data' when it tried to construct A if I declare an A like that?How else can I declare and create an object for A then? Right now I just can't declare and create variable for A from main().

Comment: I'm sorry. Xirdus' answered the question and the solution works. The error I got from the compiler mentioned in my comment above was from unimplemented A's copy constructor. Thank you.